# runonuiThread UI loop

Tags: android, multithreading, progressdialog

This is my code

I want I show the progressdialog until receive the data from server,
and when I got result from the server(if items.size>0), progressdialog will be dismiss;
But I run this code, I receive the data from the server but in runonuiThread, still running progressdialog.

```
List<ServerData> items = new ArrayList();
progressdialog.show();    

    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    HttpRequest...
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    Type type = new TypeToken<List<ServerData>>(){}.getType();
                    items = gson.fromJson(String,type);

                    Log.d("ThreadInfo","" + items.size);

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if(items.size > 0){
                                progressdialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

When I Log the ThreadInfo, It sends items.size value is 1
but still progressdialog is running and not disappear.

Question,
How I can dismiss the progressdialog when items.size is not 0?

If you have any idea, help me please.

Comment: write down your if condition before runonUIthread. it means you have to write your runonUIthread in if condition if(items.size > 0){}

Comment: @Rajesh you mean not on runonuithread? but I know about runonuithread,when I change the ui, It will be on that, so I put progressdialog in that

Comment: Why aren't you using a simple async task?

Comment: @Shmuel I use that first, so I did. I will try asynctask too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change your code like this

```
if (items.size > 0) {


    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                                progressdialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });

}
```